# How to reset a transparent 'large title' UINavigationBar to default appearance settings?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationcontroller, preferslargetitles

I'm trying to work out how to reset a transparent 'large title' nav bar to the default appearance settings.

I use the following `setTransparent()` function to configure my transparent navbar.

The `reset()` function successfully resets the default size nav bar but fails to reset the 'large title' nav bar.

```
extension UINavigationBar {

    func setTransparent() {

        // set large titles
        self.prefersLargeTitles = true

        // set colour of nav items
        self.tintColor = .white

        // set background colour
        self.barTintColor = .green

        // make transparent
        self.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        self.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.isTranslucent = true
    }

    func reset() {
        self.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
        self.shadowImage = nil
        self.isTranslucent = false
    }
}
```

I think it's something to do with 'large titles' not working with backgroundImage/shadowImage...

Answer (score 0):

You may try this function to reset at large title mode:

```
func setTransparent() {

    // set large titles
    self.prefersLargeTitles = false

    // set colour of nav items
    self.tintColor = .white

    // set background colour
    self.barTintColor = .green
self.backgroundColor = nil
    // make transparent
    self.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.isTranslucent = true
}

func reset() {
    self.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
    self.shadowImage = nil
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

    self.isTranslucent = false
   self.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.green]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the nav bar still seems to be transparent even after calling reset() in viewWillAppear()

Comment: Isn’t it green?

Comment: No, it remains transparent... I'm wondering whether this is a bug with 'large titles' in that they can't be reset?